# HTTPS POST with Args & Authentication in Ruby

Tags: ruby, git, api, post, github

I am trying to write some Ruby code to create Github repos using the API, I came up with this (based on successfully reading the repos available):

```
uri = URI("https://api.github.com/user/repos")
args = {:name => 'apitest2'}
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(args)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.basic_auth('kemra102', 'myapitoken')
response = http.request(request)
```

Sadly this errors with:

```
#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>
```

at the **irb** prompt.

Any pointers? I'm still new to Ruby and development in general so reading the documentation for all these functions has probably been more confusing than helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub requires `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8` header to be sent and payload to be sent in JSON instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded format.

See [here](https://www.socialtext.net/open/very_simple_rest_in_ruby_part_3_post_to_create_a_new_workspace) how to use Net::HTTP to POST JSON data.